# Basic XML (using Jquery to extract)

Tags: jquery, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, sabre

I want to loop through the Segments  node and it contains a segment. Each segment has it's own node and the node name either `stl19:Air` or `stl19:Hotel` and I want to extract only the Hotels - as you can see here we have values of Air, Hotel and Air in the loop - there could be zero or more hotels so I'll be created an array which will be a subset of the master array and I'll add the hotels to a bulleted list etc... There are other names too but in this example I'm just showing Hotel and Air. I can get the value of sequence with an each...

[image]

```
        $(data).find('stl19\\:Segment').each(function() {
                    
                    var seg = $(this).attr('sequence');
                    
                    $('#segmentList').append(
                        $('<li />', {
                            text: seg 
                        })
                    );
            });
```

[image]

The xml is massive ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><stl19:GetReservationRS xmlns:stl19="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_19" xmlns:ns6="http://services.sabre.com/res/orr/v0" xmlns:or114="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_14" xmlns:raw="http://tds.sabre.com/itinerary" xmlns:ns4="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrconn/ReaccSearch" Version="1.19.0"><stl19:Reservation numberInParty="1" numberOfInfants="0" NumberInSegment="1"><stl19:BookingDetails><stl19:RecordLocator>UUYMYU</stl19:RecordLocator><stl19:CreationTimestamp>2020-12-10T11:01:00</stl19:CreationTimestamp><stl19:SystemCreationTimestamp>2020-12-10T11:01:00</stl19:SystemCreationTimestamp><stl19:CreationAgentID>A46</stl19:CreationAgentID><stl19:UpdateTimestamp>2020-12-10T13:07:06</stl19:UpdateTimestamp><stl19:PNRSequence>4</stl19:PNRSequence><stl19:FlightsRange Start="2021-07-22T13:54:00" End="2021-07-23T14:29:00"/><stl19:DivideSplitDetails/><stl19:EstimatedPurgeTimestamp>2021-07-23T00:00:00</stl19:EstimatedPurgeTimestamp><stl19:UpdateToken>4184ad40e7b922cd1f63934b4fe28e5ac53c60ba5f516b52</stl19:UpdateToken></stl19:BookingDetails><stl19:POS AirExtras="false" InhibitCode="U"><stl19:Source BookingSource="29JB" AgentSine="A46" PseudoCityCode="29JB" ISOCountry="US" AgentDutyCode="*" AirlineVendorID="AA" HomePseudoCityCode="29JB" PrimeHostID="1S"/></stl19:POS><stl19:PassengerReservation><stl19:Passengers><stl19:Passenger id="11" nameType="S" referenceNumber="SAS-6785-7206" nameId="01.01" nameAssocId="1" elementId="pnr-11.1"><stl19:LastName>YOASH</stl19:LastName><stl19:FirstName>NANCY MCBRIDE</stl19:FirstName><stl19:Profiles><stl19:Profile id="12"><stl19:ProfileID>224901127</stl19:ProfileID><stl19:ProfileType>TVL</stl19:ProfileType></stl19:Profile></stl19:Profiles><stl19:Seats/></stl19:Passenger></stl19:Passengers><stl19:Segments><stl19:Poc><stl19:Airport>DCA</stl19:Airport><stl19:Departure>2021-07-22T13:54:00</stl19:Departure></stl19:Poc><stl19:Segment sequence="1" id="22"><stl19:Air id="22" sequence="1" segmentAssociationId="3" isPast="false" DayOfWeekInd="4" CodeShare="false" SpecialMeal="false" SmokingAllowed="false" ResBookDesigCode="Y" Code="**"><stl19:DepartureAirport>DCA</stl19:DepartureAirport><stl19:DepartureAirportCodeContext>IATA</stl19:DepartureAirportCodeContext><stl19:ArrivalAirport>RDU</stl19:ArrivalAirport><stl19:ArrivalAirportCodeContext>IATA</stl19:ArrivalAirportCodeContext><stl19:OperatingAirlineCode>AA</stl19:OperatingAirlineCode><stl19:OperatingAirlineShortName>AMERICAN AIRLINES</stl19:OperatingAirlineShortName><stl19:OperatingFlightNumber>5430</stl19:OperatingFlightNumber><stl19:EquipmentType>CR7</stl19:EquipmentType><stl19:MarketingAirlineCode>AA</stl19:MarketingAirlineCode><stl19:MarketingFlightNumber>5430</stl19:MarketingFlightNumber><stl19:OperatingClassOfService>Y</stl19:OperatingClassOfService><stl19:MarketingClassOfService>Y</stl19:MarketingClassOfService><stl19:MarriageGrp><stl19:Ind>0</stl19:Ind><stl19:Group>0</stl19:Group><stl19:Sequence>0</stl19:Sequence></stl19:MarriageGrp><stl19:Seats/><stl19:AirlineRefId>DCAA*UUYMYU</stl19:AirlineRefId><stl19:Eticket>true</stl19:Eticket><stl19:DepartureDateTime>2021-07-22T13:54:00</stl19:DepartureDateTime><stl19:ArrivalDateTime>2021-07-22T15:10:00</stl19:ArrivalDateTime><stl19:FlightNumber>5430</stl19:FlightNumber><stl19:ClassOfService>Y</stl19:ClassOfService><stl19:ActionCode>HK</stl19:ActionCode><stl19:NumberInParty>1</stl19:NumberInParty><stl19:SegmentSpecialRequests/><stl19:inboundConnection>false</stl19:inboundConnection><stl19:outboundConnection>false</stl19:outboundConnection><stl19:ScheduleChangeIndicator>false</stl19:ScheduleChangeIndicator><stl19:SegmentBookedDate>2020-12-10T13:03:00</stl19:SegmentBookedDate><stl19:Pos><stl19:IataNumber>3460147</stl19:IataNumber><stl19:AgencyCityCode>RDU</stl19:AgencyCityCode><stl19:CountryCode>US</stl19:CountryCode><stl19:DutyCode>*</stl19:DutyCode></stl19:Pos><stl19:Banner>MARKETED BY AMERICAN AIRLINES</stl19:Banner><stl19:Informational>false</stl19:Informational></stl19:Air></stl19:Segment><stl19:Segment sequence="2" id="56"><stl19:Hotel id="56" sequence="2" isPast="false"><or114:Reservation DayOfWeekInd="4" NumberInParty="01"><or114:LineNumber>2</or114:LineNumber><or114:LineType>HHL</or114:LineType><or114:LineStatus>HK</or114:LineStatus><or114:POSRequestorID>34601475</or114:POSRequestorID><or114:RoomType><or114:RoomTypeCode>QAA</or114:RoomTypeCode><or114:NumberOfUnits>1</or114:NumberOfUnits><or114:ShortText>QAAD00</or114:ShortText></or114:RoomType><or114:RoomRates><or114:AmountBeforeTax>127.00</or114:AmountBeforeTax><or114:CurrencyCode>USD</or114:CurrencyCode></or114:RoomRates><or114:RateAccessCodeBooked><or114:RateAccessCode>AAA</or114:RateAccessCode><or114:CategoryTypeCode>R</or114:CategoryTypeCode></or114:RateAccessCodeBooked><or114:GuestCounts><or114:GuestCount>1</or114:GuestCount><or114:ExtraGuestCount>0</or114:ExtraGuestCount><or114:RollAwayCount>0</or114:RollAwayCount><or114:CribCount>0</or114:CribCount><or114:ReserveUnderName>YOASH NANCY MCBRIDE</or114:ReserveUnderName><or114:Name>YOASH NANCY MCBRIDE</or114:Name></or114:GuestCounts><or114:TimeSpanStart>2021-07-22T15:10:00</or114:TimeSpanStart><or114:TimeSpanDuration>1</or114:TimeSpanDuration><or114:TimeSpanEnd>2021-07-23T13:17:00</or114:TimeSpanEnd><or114:Guarantee><or114:Text>GVI4XXXXXXXXXXX1111EXP 08 23-YOASH</or114:Text></or114:Guarantee><or114:ChainCode>CY</or114:ChainCode><or114:HotelCode>23869</or114:HotelCode><or114:HotelCityCode>RDU</or114:HotelCityCode><or114:HotelName>COURTYARD RALEIGH DURHAM-AIRPRT</or114:HotelName><or114:HotelTotalPricing><or114:TotalTax Amount="16.83"><or114:Tax Id="1">9.21 OCCUPANCY TAX</or114:Tax><or114:Tax Id="2">7.62 COUNTY TAX</or114:Tax></or114:TotalTax><or114:ApproximateTotal AmountAndCurrency="143.83 USD"/><or114:Disclaimer Id="1">INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</or114:Disclaimer></or114:HotelTotalPricing></or114:Reservation><or114:AdditionalInformation><or114:ConfirmationNumber DirectConnect="true">81532843-</or114:ConfirmationNumber><or114:Address><or114:AddressLine>2001 HOSPITALITY CT</or114:AddressLine><or114:AddressLine>MORRISVILLE NC 27560</or114:AddressLine><or114:CountryCode>US</or114:CountryCode><or114:City>MORRISVILLE</or114:City><or114:State>NC</or114:State><or114:ZipCode>27560</or114:ZipCode></or114:Address><or114:ContactNumbers><or114:PhoneNumber>919-467-9444</or114:PhoneNumber><or114:FaxNumber>919-467-9332</or114:FaxNumber></or114:ContactNumbers><or114:CancelPenaltyPolicyCode>01D</or114:CancelPenaltyPolicyCode><or114:Commission><or114:Indicator>C</or114:Indicator><or114:Text>COMMISSIONABLE</or114:Text></or114:Commission></or114:AdditionalInformation><or114:SegmentText>127.00USD/RQ-W,C,F,P,S,R,I/RC-@@@-AAA-R/TTX-16.83/HTP-143.83 USD/TX1-9.21 OCCUPANCY TAX/TX2-7.62 COUNTY TAX/DS1-INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES/CMN-C/CMT-COMMISSIONABLE/AGT-34601475/G-VI4XXXXXXXXXXX1111EXP 08 23-YOASH/NM-YOASH NANCY MCBRIDE/C-01D/ARR-1510/DEP-1317/XS-D8F3128F22DE3B8A55E6F8A000000000/XT-55E6F8A0/XL-0000/DT-10DEC200786/SBS-HS/HSA-2001 HOSPITALITY CT$MORRISVILLE NC 27560/HFN-COURTYARD RALEIGH DURHAM-AIRPRT/HCY-MORRISVILLE/HST-NC/HCC-US/HPC-27560/HPH-919-467-9444/HFX-919-467-9332/UID-D8F3129006276F8A55E6F8/SI-/CF-81532843-</or114:SegmentText></stl19:Hotel><stl19:Product sequence="2" id="56"><or114:ProductBase><or114:SegmentReference>56</or114:SegmentReference></or114:ProductBase><or114:ProductDetails vendorCode="CY" statusCode="HK" previousStatusCode="SS" startDateTime="2021-07-22T00:00:00" endDateTime="2021-07-23T00:00:00"><or114:ProductName type="HHL"/><or114:Hotel id="56" sequence="3" isPast="false"><or114:Reservation DayOfWeekInd="4" NumberInParty="01"><or114:LineNumber>2</or114:LineNumber><or114:LineType>HHL</or114:LineType><or114:LineStatus>HK</or114:LineStatus><or114:POSRequestorID>34601475</or114:POSRequestorID><or114:RoomType><or114:RoomTypeCode>QAA</or114:RoomTypeCode><or114:NumberOfUnits>1</or114:NumberOfUnits><or114:ShortText>QAAD00</or114:ShortText></or114:RoomType><or114:RoomRates><or114:AmountBeforeTax>127.00</or114:AmountBeforeTax><or114:CurrencyCode>USD</or114:CurrencyCode></or114:RoomRates><or114:RateAccessCodeBooked><or114:RateAccessCode>AAA</or114:RateAccessCode><or114:CategoryTypeCode>R</or114:CategoryTypeCode></or114:RateAccessCodeBooked><or114:GuestCounts><or114:GuestCount>1</or114:GuestCount><or114:ExtraGuestCount>0</or114:ExtraGuestCount><or114:RollAwayCount>0</or114:RollAwayCount><or114:CribCount>0</or114:CribCount><or114:ReserveUnderName>YOASH NANCY MCBRIDE</or114:ReserveUnderName><or114:Name>YOASH NANCY MCBRIDE</or114:Name></or114:GuestCounts><or114:TimeSpanStart>2021-07-22T15:10:00</or114:TimeSpanStart><or114:TimeSpanDuration>1</or114:TimeSpanDuration><or114:TimeSpanEnd>2021-07-23T13:17:00</or114:TimeSpanEnd><or114:Guarantee><or114:Text>GVI4XXXXXXXXXXX1111EXP 08 23-YOASH</or114:Text></or114:Guarantee><or114:ChainCode>CY</or114:ChainCode><or114:HotelCode>23869</or114:HotelCode><or114:HotelCityCode>RDU</or114:HotelCityCode><or114:HotelName>COURTYARD RALEIGH DURHAM-AIRPRT</or114:HotelName><or114:HotelTotalPricing CurrencyCode="USD"><or114:TotalTax Amount="16.83"><or114:Tax>16.83</or114:Tax><or114:Tax Id="2">7.62 COUNTY TAX</or114:Tax></or114:TotalTax><or114:ApproximateTotal AmountAndCurrency="143.83 USD"/><or114:Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</or114:Disclaimer></or114:HotelTotalPricing></or114:Reservation><or114:AdditionalInformation><or114:ConfirmationNumber DirectConnect="false">81532843-</or114:ConfirmationNumber><or114:Address><or114:AddressLine>2001 HOSPITALITY CT$MORRISVILLE NC 27560</or114:AddressLine><or114:AddressLine>MORRISVILLE NC 27560</or114:AddressLine><or114:CountryCode>US</or114:CountryCode><or114:City>MORRISVILLE</or114:City><or114:State>NC</or114:State><or114:ZipCode>27560</or114:ZipCode></or114:Address><or114:ContactNumbers><or114:PhoneNumber>919-467-9444</or114:PhoneNumber><or114:FaxNumber>919-467-9332</or114:FaxNumber></or114:ContactNumbers><or114:CancelPenaltyPolicyCode>01D</or114:CancelPenaltyPolicyCode><or114:Commission><or114:Indicator>C</or114:Indicator><or114:Text>COMMISSIONABLE</or114:Text></or114:Commission></or114:AdditionalInformation><or114:SegmentText>127.00USD/RQ-W,C,F,P,S,R,I/RC-@@@-AAA-R/TTX-16.83/HTP-143.83 USD/TX1-9.21 OCCUPANCY TAX/TX2-7.62 COUNTY TAX/DS1-INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES/CMN-C/CMT-COMMISSIONABLE/AGT-34601475/G-VI4XXXXXXXXXXX1111EXP 08 23-YOASH/NM-YOASH NANCY MCBRIDE/C-01D/ARR-1510/DEP-1317/XS-D8F3128F22DE3B8A55E6F8A000000000/XT-55E6F8A0/XL-0000/DT-10DEC200786/SBS-HS/HSA-2001 HOSPITALITY CT$MORRISVILLE NC 27560/HFN-COURTYARD RALEIGH DURHAM-AIRPRT/HCY-MORRISVILLE/HST-NC/HCC-US/HPC-27560/HPH-919-467-9444/HFX-919-467-9332/UID-D8F3129006276F8A55E6F8/SI-/CF-81532843-</or114:SegmentText><or114:RateDescription><or114:TextLine>AAA AMERICAN AUTO ASSO</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>AAA RATE, AAA MEMBERSHIP CARD REQUIRED, GUEST ROOM, 1 KING,</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine> SOFA BED</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>FACE COVERINGS ARE REQUIRED. CUSTOMERS SHOULD REVIEW</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>GOVERNMENT GUIDANCE TO CONFIRM ELIGIBILITY TO TRAVEL - STAY</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>AT HOTEL. SEE TRAVELGUIDANCE.MARRIOTT.COM.</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>MAX OCCUPANCY- 5 GUESTS</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>1 KING, SOFA BED,</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>351SQFT 32SQM, WIRELESS INTERNET, COMPLIMENTARY,</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>COFFEE TEA MAKER, 42IN 107CM TV</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>AMERICAN AUTO ASSOCIATION RATE</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>- AVAILABLE TO AAA MEMBERS ONLY.</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>- LIMIT OF TWO ROOMS PER AAA MEMBER PER NIGHT.</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>- AAA MEMBERSHIP CARD REQUIRED AT CHECK-IN.</or114:TextLine></or114:RateDescription><or114:HotelPolicy><or114:GuaranteePolicy>REQUIRED</or114:GuaranteePolicy><or114:CancellationPolicy>CANCEL 1 DAYS PRIOR TO ARRIVAL</or114:CancellationPolicy><or114:AdditionalPolicy><or114:TextLine>CANCELLATION-CANCEL PERMITTED UP TO 01 DAYS BEFORE ARRIVAL</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>143.83 USD CANCEL FEE PER ROOM</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>OTHER-ALL RATES AT THIS HOTEL INCLUDE COMPLIMENTARY IN-ROOM HIGH</or114:TextLine><or114:TextLine>SPEED INTERNET ACCESS AND MINI-REFRIGERATOR.</or114:TextLine></or114:AdditionalPolicy></or114:HotelPolicy></or114:Hotel></or114:ProductDetails></stl19:Product></stl19:Segment><stl19:Segment sequence="3" id="16"><stl19:Air id="16" sequence="3" segmentAssociationId="2" isPast="false" DayOfWeekInd="5" CodeShare="false" SpecialMeal="false" SmokingAllowed="false" ResBookDesigCode="Y" Code="**"><stl19:DepartureAirport>RDU</stl19:DepartureAirport><stl19:DepartureAirportCodeContext>IATA</stl19:DepartureAirportCodeContext><stl19:ArrivalAirport>DCA</stl19:ArrivalAirport><stl19:ArrivalAirportCodeContext>IATA</stl19:ArrivalAirportCodeContext><stl19:OperatingAirlineCode>AA</stl19:OperatingAirlineCode><stl19:OperatingAirlineShortName>AMERICAN AIRLINES</stl19:OperatingAirlineShortName><stl19:OperatingFlightNumber>5660</stl19:OperatingFlightNumber><stl19:EquipmentType>CR7</stl19:EquipmentType><stl19:MarketingAirlineCode>AA</stl19:MarketingAirlineCode><stl19:MarketingFlightNumber>5660</stl19:MarketingFlightNumber><stl19:OperatingClassOfService>Y</stl19:OperatingClassOfService><stl19:MarketingClassOfService>Y</stl19:MarketingClassOfService><stl19:MarriageGrp><stl19:Ind>0</stl19:Ind><stl19:Group>0</stl19:Group><stl19:Sequence>0</stl19:Sequence></stl19:MarriageGrp><stl19:Seats/><stl19:AirlineRefId>DCAA*UUYMYU</stl19:AirlineRefId><stl19:Eticket>true</stl19:Eticket><stl19:DepartureDateTime>2021-07-23T13:17:00</stl19:DepartureDateTime><stl19:ArrivalDateTime>2021-07-23T14:29:00</stl19:ArrivalDateTime><stl19:FlightNumber>5660</stl19:FlightNumber><stl19:ClassOfService>Y</stl19:ClassOfService><stl19:ActionCode>HK</stl19:ActionCode><stl19:NumberInParty>1</stl19:NumberInParty><stl19:SegmentSpecialRequests/><stl19:inboundConnection>false</stl19:inboundConnection><stl19:outboundConnection>false</stl19:outboundConnection><stl19:ScheduleChangeIndicator>false</stl19:ScheduleChangeIndicator><stl19:SegmentBookedDate>2020-12-10T11:01:00</stl19:SegmentBookedDate><stl19:Pos><stl19:IataNumber>3460147</stl19:IataNumber><stl19:AgencyCityCode>RDU</stl19:AgencyCityCode><stl19:CountryCode>US</stl19:CountryCode><stl19:DutyCode>*</stl19:DutyCode></stl19:Pos><stl19:Banner>MARKETED BY AMERICAN AIRLINES</stl19:Banner><stl19:Informational>false</stl19:Informational></stl19:Air></stl19:Segment></stl19:Segments><stl19:FormsOfPayment><stl19:CreditCardPayment ShortText="CREDIT CARD DATA EXISTS *CC TO DISPLAY"/></stl19:FormsOfPayment><stl19:TicketingInfo><stl19:AlreadyTicketed id="17" index="1" elementId="pnr-17"><stl19:Code>T-A</stl19:Code><stl19:Comment>TEST PNR</stl19:Comment></stl19:AlreadyTicketed></stl19:TicketingInfo><stl19:ItineraryPricing/></stl19:PassengerReservation><stl19:DKNumbers><stl19:DKNumber>1234567890</stl19:DKNumber></stl19:DKNumbers><stl19:ReceivedFrom><stl19:Name>PAX/NAM</stl19:Name></stl19:ReceivedFrom><stl19:Addresses><stl19:Address><stl19:AddressLines><stl19:AddressLine id="6" type="O"><stl19:Text>SAS INSTITUTE</stl19:Text></stl19:AddressLine><stl19:AddressLine id="7" type="O"><stl19:Text>SAS CAMPUS DRIVE</stl19:Text></stl19:AddressLine><stl19:AddressLine id="8" type="O"><stl19:Text>CARY NC 27513</stl19:Text></stl19:AddressLine><stl19:AddressLine id="9" type="O"><stl19:Text>US</stl19:Text></stl19:AddressLine></stl19:AddressLines></stl19:Address></stl19:Addresses><stl19:PhoneNumbers><stl19:PhoneNumber id="3" index="1" elementId="pnr-3"><stl19:CityCode>RDU</stl19:CityCode><stl19:Number>919-531-7894-A A</stl19:Number></stl19:PhoneNumber><stl19:PhoneNumber id="13" index="2" elementId="pnr-13"><stl19:CityCode>RDU</stl19:CityCode><stl19:Number>9195318350</stl19:Number></stl19:PhoneNumber></stl19:PhoneNumbers><stl19:Remarks><stl19:Remark index="1" id="67" type="HS" elementId="pnr-67"><stl19:RemarkLines><stl19:RemarkLine><stl19:Text>AGY/CSL-D9463352-1CFF-4930-8A53-CA076EC43966/81532843-</stl19:Text></stl19:RemarkLine></stl19:RemarkLines></stl19:Remark></stl19:Remarks><stl19:EmailAddresses><stl19:EmailAddress id="14"><stl19:Address>NANCY.YOASH@SAS.COM</stl19:Address><stl19:Comment/></stl19:EmailAddress></stl19:EmailAddresses><stl19:GenericSpecialRequests id="57" type="G" msgType="O"><stl19:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  D AAA AMERICAN AUTO ASSO</stl19:FreeText><stl19:AirlineCode>CY</stl19:AirlineCode><stl19:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  D AAA AMERICAN AUTO ASSO</stl19:FullText></stl19:GenericSpecialRequests><stl19:GenericSpecialRequests id="58" type="G" msgType="O"><stl19:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  D AAA RATE, AAA MEMBERSHIP CARD</stl19:FreeText><stl19:AirlineCode>CY</stl19:AirlineCode><stl19:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  D AAA RATE, AAA MEMBERSHIP CARD</stl19:FullText></stl19:GenericSpecialRequests><stl19:GenericSpecialRequests id="59" type="G" msgType="O"><stl19:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  D  SOFA BED</stl19:FreeText><stl19:AirlineCode>CY</stl19:AirlineCode><stl19:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  D  SOFA BED</stl19:FullText></stl19:GenericSpecialRequests><stl19:GenericSpecialRequests id="60" type="G" msgType="O"><stl19:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  TTX 16.83 TTL TAX</stl19:FreeText><stl19:AirlineCode>CY</stl19:AirlineCode><stl19:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  TTX 16.83 TTL TAX</stl19:FullText></stl19:GenericSpecialRequests><stl19:GenericSpecialRequests id="61" type="G" msgType="O"><stl19:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  TX 9.21 OCCUPANCY TAX</stl19:FreeText><stl19:AirlineCode>CY</stl19:AirlineCode><stl19:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  TX 9.21 OCCUPANCY TAX</stl19:FullText></stl19:GenericSpecialRequests><stl19:GenericSpecialRequests id="62" type="G" msgType="O"><stl19:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  TX 7.62 COUNTY TAX</stl19:FreeText><stl19:AirlineCode>CY</stl19:AirlineCode><stl19:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  TX 7.62 COUNTY TAX</stl19:FullText></stl19:GenericSpecialRequests><stl19:GenericSpecialRequests id="63" type="G" msgType="O"><stl19:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  TP 143.83 USD APPROX. TTL PRICE</stl19:FreeText><stl19:AirlineCode>CY</stl19:AirlineCode><stl19:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  TP 143.83 USD APPROX. TTL PRICE</stl19:FullText></stl19:GenericSpecialRequests><stl19:GenericSpecialRequests id="64" type="G" msgType="O"><stl19:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  TD INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</stl19:FreeText><stl19:AirlineCode>CY</stl19:AirlineCode><stl19:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  TD INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</stl19:FullText></stl19:GenericSpecialRequests><stl19:Profiles><stl19:Profile id="4"><stl19:ProfileID>224901131</stl19:ProfileID><stl19:ProfileType>OPX</stl19:ProfileType></stl19:Profile><stl19:Profile id="10"><stl19:ProfileID>224901133</stl19:ProfileID><stl19:ProfileType>CRP</stl19:ProfileType></stl19:Profile></stl19:Profiles><stl19:AssociationMatrices><stl19:AssociationMatrix><stl19:Name>PssIDType</stl19:Name><stl19:Parent ref="pnr-56"/><stl19:Child ref="pnr-or-6"/></stl19:AssociationMatrix></stl19:AssociationMatrices><stl19:OpenReservationElements><or114:OpenReservationElement id="4" type="PROFILE" elementId="pnr-or-4"><or114:Profile><or114:ID>224901131</or114:ID><or114:Type>OPERATION</or114:Type><or114:ShortType>OPX</or114:ShortType><or114:OwningAgency>29JB</or114:OwningAgency></or114:Profile></or114:OpenReservationElement><or114:OpenReservationElement id="10" type="PROFILE" elementId="pnr-or-10"><or114:Profile><or114:ID>224901133</or114:ID><or114:Type>CORPID</or114:Type><or114:ShortType>CRP</or114:ShortType><or114:OwningAgency>29JB</or114:OwningAgency></or114:Profile></or114:OpenReservationElement><or114:OpenReservationElement id="12" type="PROFILE" elementId="pnr-or-12"><or114:Profile><or114:ID>224901127</or114:ID><or114:Type>TRAVELER</or114:Type><or114:ShortType>TVL</or114:ShortType><or114:OwningAgency>29JB</or114:OwningAgency></or114:Profile><or114:NameAssociation><or114:LastName>YOASH</or114:LastName><or114:FirstName>NANCY MCBRIDE</or114:FirstName><or114:ReferenceId>1</or114:ReferenceId><or114:Id>1</or114:Id><or114:NameRefNumber>01.01</or114:NameRefNumber></or114:NameAssociation></or114:OpenReservationElement><or114:OpenReservationElement id="57" type="SRVC" elementId="pnr-57"><or114:ServiceRequest airlineCode="CY" serviceType="OSI" ssrType="GFX"><or114:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  D AAA AMERICAN AUTO ASSO</or114:FreeText><or114:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  D AAA AMERICAN AUTO ASSO        </or114:FullText></or114:ServiceRequest></or114:OpenReservationElement><or114:OpenReservationElement id="58" type="SRVC" elementId="pnr-58"><or114:ServiceRequest airlineCode="CY" serviceType="OSI" ssrType="GFX"><or114:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  D AAA RATE, AAA MEMBERSHIP CARD</or114:FreeText><or114:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  D AAA RATE, AAA MEMBERSHIP CARD </or114:FullText></or114:ServiceRequest></or114:OpenReservationElement><or114:OpenReservationElement id="59" type="SRVC" elementId="pnr-59"><or114:ServiceRequest airlineCode="CY" serviceType="OSI" ssrType="GFX"><or114:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  D  SOFA BED</or114:FreeText><or114:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  D  SOFA BED                     </or114:FullText></or114:ServiceRequest></or114:OpenReservationElement><or114:OpenReservationElement id="60" type="SRVC" elementId="pnr-60"><or114:ServiceRequest airlineCode="CY" serviceType="OSI" ssrType="GFX"><or114:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  TTX 16.83 TTL TAX</or114:FreeText><or114:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  TTX 16.83 TTL TAX</or114:FullText></or114:ServiceRequest></or114:OpenReservationElement><or114:OpenReservationElement id="61" type="SRVC" elementId="pnr-61"><or114:ServiceRequest airlineCode="CY" serviceType="OSI" ssrType="GFX"><or114:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  TX 9.21 OCCUPANCY TAX</or114:FreeText><or114:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  TX 9.21 OCCUPANCY TAX</or114:FullText></or114:ServiceRequest></or114:OpenReservationElement><or114:OpenReservationElement id="62" type="SRVC" elementId="pnr-62"><or114:ServiceRequest airlineCode="CY" serviceType="OSI" ssrType="GFX"><or114:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  TX 7.62 COUNTY TAX</or114:FreeText><or114:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  TX 7.62 COUNTY TAX</or114:FullText></or114:ServiceRequest></or114:OpenReservationElement><or114:OpenReservationElement id="63" type="SRVC" elementId="pnr-63"><or114:ServiceRequest airlineCode="CY" serviceType="OSI" ssrType="GFX"><or114:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  TP 143.83 USD APPROX. TTL PRICE</or114:FreeText><or114:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  TP 143.83 USD APPROX. TTL PRICE</or114:FullText></or114:ServiceRequest></or114:OpenReservationElement><or114:OpenReservationElement id="64" type="SRVC" elementId="pnr-64"><or114:ServiceRequest airlineCode="CY" serviceType="OSI" ssrType="GFX"><or114:FreeText>HHL   23869 QAAD00  TD INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</or114:FreeText><or114:FullText>CY HHL   23869 QAAD00  TD INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</or114:FullText></or114:ServiceRequest></or114:OpenReservationElement><or114:OpenReservationElement id="14" type="PSG_DETAILS_MAIL" elementId="pnr-14"><or114:Email comment=""><or114:Address>NANCY.YOASH@SAS.COM</or114:Address></or114:Email></or114:OpenReservationElement></stl19:OpenReservationElements></stl19:Reservation></stl19:GetReservationRS>
```

Comment: can you add your xml in `text` ?

Comment: What you posted isn't xml; just text. Can you simply post the url?

Comment: You say that "I want to extract only the value of Air, Hotel and Air". Can you edit your question and clarify which "value" **exactly** from **each** of these two nodes (you repeat AIr twice) are you trying to extract?

Comment: Sorry about that Jack... any better?

Comment: If understand you correctly, you are trying to extract the value of the `Sequence` attribute of the `Air` and `Hotel` node children of `<Segment>` and wrap each of them in `<li>` tags. It can be done using xpath, but from my limited understanding of jquery, jquery doesn't support xpath. It can be done with pure javascript, however.